# How to find and replace based on a condition?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of JSON files and would like to replace some fields, but only if a condition in another field holds.

Example: I want to replace `"field1" : "abc"` with `"field1" : "qrs"`, but only if `"field2" : "cdf"` is present in the file. So, `json1` should be edited, but not `json2`. The fields in the JSON files are not in a specific order.

`json1 = { "field1" : "abc", "field2" : "cdf" }`

`json2 = { "field1" : "abc", "field2" : "xyz" }`

Comment: Can you do 2 successive searches?  first for those files containing the `field2` key/value and then in those files only do your `field1` find/replace.  I know of at least one extension that makes that easy - you can do it in one step.  Let me know if this would wokr for you.

Comment: Two searches are fine. The only requirement is that the changes are picked up by source control.
If I open the search in the editor, I can do another find and replace, which gives the desired results, but I do not see a way to save these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an extension that I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), it is easy to do successive searches.  And then use only positive results from a prior search as the `files to include` for the next search.

Here is an example keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) for your example case:

```
{
  "key": "alt+b",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runInSearchPanel",
  "args": {
    
    "find": ["\"field2\"\\s*:\\s*\"cdf\"", "(\"field1\"\\s*:\\s*)\"abc\""],
    "delay": 2000,
    "replace": ["", "$1\"qrs\""],
    
    "filesToInclude": ["", "${resultsFiles}"],
    
    "isRegex": true,
    "triggerSearch": true,
    "triggerReplaceAll": [false, true]
  }
}
```

This does two searches (in the find array) and one replace - the `""` replace won't do anything to your files.

The `filesToInclude` will be populated with those files with a positive hit from the previous search.

- if you are searching through a lot of files increase the delay (milliseconds)
- note double escapes are necessary

`"filesToInclude": ["", "${resultsFiles}"],` so first search is within all files and second search is within the positive results from prior search only.

[image: two searches within files from first search]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mark. Do you have a somewhat more comprehensive tutorial for the not so seasoned VSC/regex user?

Comment: What is the area you are having difficulty understanding?  Something about the extension itself or something about vscode?

Comment: I can not find how to get started with the extension in VSC.

Comment: Extensions info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace.  Keyboards Shortcuts: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor